# Interfacing with gnuplot in c++ using popen?

Tags: c++

I'm having a weird problem in my c++ program. I used `popen()` to open gnuplot and communicate with it using `fprintf(gnuplot,"command line")`.  The problem that occurred when I tried to use this gnuplot command: `set output "nameofthefile.ps"` is that the statement in the program becomes separated:

```
fprintf(gnuplot,"set output "`plot.ps`" \n");
```

plot.ps got out of the `" "` and when I compile it says:

```
main.cpp:54:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘plot’
  fprintf(gnuplot,"set output "plot.ps" \n");
```

How do I solve this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't escape your strings properly. Try:

```
fprintf(gnuplot,"set output \"plot.ps\" \n");
```

You can't have `"`s within a string by themselfes or it'll end the string.